# Parsing through a json list but only for one item in the list

Tags: jquery

This works well to parse through everything in the json object but how can I modify the code to give me just one item in the list? For example, what if I just wanted to output item number two? Reason for asking: In another project I'm re-doing a jquery quiz and I want to output each question on a separate page. Therefore page 2 would hold question 2, page 3 would hold question 3 and so on. Thanks very much.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jsonp = '[{"Language":"jQuery","ID":"1"},{"Language":"C#","ID":"2"}, {"Language":"Javascript","ID":"3"} , {"Language":"ActionScript","ID":"4"}]';
    var lang = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    $.each(obj, function() {
        lang += this['Language'] + "<br/>";
    });
    $('span').html(lang);
});
```

Comment: You mean like `var lang = obj[1].Language`? Then, there it is ...

Comment: When I tried that it says, "Cannot read property '1' of undefined.

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere else ... see https://jsfiddle.net/tj667sn7/1/

Comment: Got it now. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, glad it worked. I made it an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single Language entry from your array, just access it by the array index:

```
var lang = obj[1].Language;
```

[Wokring example.](https://jsfiddle.net/tj667sn7/2/)